# Measure theory - Fubini

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on this problem: let $A\subset [0,1], B\subset [0,1]$ both Lebesgue-measurable, each with measure $1/2$. Prove there exists $x\in[-1,1]$ such that $m((A+x)\cap B) \ge 1/10$. Here $A+x=\{y\in \mathbb{R} |y-x\in A\}$ and the hint is to use Fubini.

Well, I see that $\chi_{(A+x)\cap B}(y)=\chi_A(y-x)\chi_B(y)$, also for $x,y\in[0,1]$ indeed $y-x\in[-1,1]$, also $m(A)=m(A+x)$ (translation invariance), I also understand how to use Fubini on $\chi_A(y-x)\chi_B(y)$, but I am a little stuck with how to conclude.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in[-1,1]$, let $f(x) = m((A+x)\cap B)$. Then we can write
$$ f(x) = \int\limits_{-1}^{1}{\chi_{(A+x)\cap B}(y)\text{ d}y}. $$
To show that $f(x)\ge 1/10$ for some value of $x$, it suffices to show that the average value of $f$ is at least $1/10$, i.e. to show that
$$ \int\limits_{-1}^{1}{f(x)\text{ d}x} \ge\frac{2}{10}. $$
Can you use Fubini's theorem to conclude?

Comment: Yes! Thank you soo much!

Comment: @AndroidNetizen No problem!